# How to create work timer with a given time in JS

Tags: javascript, timer

I am figuring out on how to create a work timer that records the hours and minutes of the user. Example I have a working hours of 3:42 from the database. I just need to know how can I resume or increment that in real time using js or jquery in hours and minutes format only.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the time string to number of seconds.

```
var time = '3:45'.split(':');
var seconds = time[0] * 3600 + time[1] * 60;
```

Increment that amount by one every second and every minute maybe write back to the database.

```
setInterval(function() {

    seconds++; 
    if (seconds % 60 == 0) 
    {
        // Write back to the database here
    }

}, 1000);
```

Comment: Do you have a sample codes in js in converting time string to seconds?

Comment: Split the string by ':' with string.split() and then seconds = hours * 3600 + minutes * 60

Answer (score -1):

Re-format that time to minutes and increment with `setInterval(function () {$minutes++}, 60000);`. It will increment your time every minute. Than format it back to `H:m` for display.